# Angularjs - tinyMCE 4 directive not working after using sortable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm building a project with AngularJS using AngularUI directives: ui.tinymce and ui.sortable.

Here is my code:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions"  ng-model="appData.data">
<li ng-repeat="box in appData.data" boxlistitem>
    <textarea ng-model="box.title" value="{{box.title}}" class="tinyMCE" ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions"></textarea>
</li>
</ul>
```

Basically it works great, but a strange thing happens once I'm sorting one of the list items - the tinyMCE not working any more (see the attached images - the left one is how it suppose to be).

[image]
[image]

Any idea what might be the problem?

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel,

It's a known issue, I have managed to work it out with ng-include, so that the tinymce textarea will be in it.

like this:

```
<ul ui-sortable="sortableOptions"  ng-model="appData.data">
  <li ng-repeat="box in appData.data" boxlistitem ng-include src="box.template_name">
  </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="tinymce_module">
  <textarea ng-model="box.title" value="{{box.title}}" class="tinyMCE" ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions"></textarea>
</script>
```

and in the controller you need to do something like this:

```
$scope.sortableOptions =
  update: (e, ui) ->
    box.template_name = ""
    $timeout ->
      box.template_name = "tinymce_module"
    ,0
```

just find your way to pass the {{box}} to the update function in sortableOptions, that will reload the tinymce plugin with all of it's data.

Good luck.

Comment: Pure awesomeness! Thank you so much Leon, it worked perfectly!

Comment: My pleasure Daniel :)